# Store local object in global object

Tags: javascript, object, scope

The function generates new objects - we dont know before hand - and I want to store them for later. Is this ok:

```
var objs = {};// container

(function doSth(){// might has to add new objects
  var ob1 = {id: 29938, name: 'name1'};
  objs['ob1'] = ob1;// ???
  objs['ob2'] = {id: 2000, name: 'name2'};// ???
})()

 // use the obj later on like 
 console.log(objs['ob1'].id); 
 console.log(objs['ob2'].name);
```

I create a new object on the heap and store the reference inside the global object for later use. Because I store the reference no garbage collection is done and the access is ok, I assume. 
**[JsFiddle for this.](https://jsfiddle.net/wssj5qsg/10/)**

Comment: Of course. Any object that can be accessed is not garbage, so it's not collected.

Comment: There's no such thing as local and global objects. There are just local and global variables.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. It'll work perfectly.

Comment: You have complete code here to demonstrate whether or not it works, did you try running it to see what happens?

Comment: yes it works, but this does not suffice its got to do so. I asked because in the irc javascript some guys seemed to have trolled me saying its bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

> ...This algorithm reduces the definition of "an object is not needed anymore" to "an object has no other object referencing to it". An object is considered garbage collectable if there is zero reference pointing at this object.

So as long as you have a reference to those objects they won't be garbage collected.
For Example:

```
  var o = { 
    a: {
      b: 2
    }
  }; // 2 objects are created. One is referenced by the other as one of its properties.
     // The other is referenced by virtue of being assigned to the 'o' variable.
     // Obviously, none can be garbage-collected
     // You can also free the memory by removing all references to that object, e.g.,
     o.a = null;
```